# dx(t)/dx vs. dx/dx

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to symbolic MATLAB and WolframAlpha,

$\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial x}  = 0, \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = 1$

I came across this while trying to figure out how to do:

$\frac {\partial} {\partial x} \int \dot x dt$

How can this be?

Answer (score 2):

Think about $\frac{dx}{dx}$ as $\frac{d}{dx}(x)$ which means the derivative of the function $x$ (taking $x$ to be the variable--from the denominator of the fraction).  Whereas $\frac{dx(t)}{dx}$ means $\frac{d}{dx}(x(t))$ so the derivative with respect to $x$ of some function of $t$.  A function of $t$ has no variable $x$, so appears as a constant.  Hence, the derivative is $0$.  For example, think $\frac{d}{dx}(t^2)=0$... here $x(t)=t^2$.

Comment: its actually $\dot x$ or $\frac{dx} {dt}$, the term inside of the integral.

Comment: @KristofferCatabui: Ok, well in that case, the derivative would be zero since the result of the integral is a function of $t$ and you take the derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: Hmm, then how come I can take $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ when $y(t)=t^2$ and $x(t)=t^3$, there is no x in y here either. So how come it works like this?

Comment: Because you can write $y=t^2=\frac{t^3}{t}=\frac{x}{t}$.  So $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @KristofferCatabui, I had sort of assumed that you had mis-used the notation for partial derivatives (the question was un-clear, and people frequently mis-use that).  If I really misunderstood what you asked, I can remove my answer.  I tried to be careful in the answer to not use partial derivatives so that what I said was true.

Comment: Maybe a little more context can clear this up a bit, I'm trying to take the Jacobian with respect to [x; y; z] of [int(dx/dt *dt); int(dy/dt *dt); int(dz/dt *dt)]

I'll fix the formatting later, am in a hurry, sorry.

Comment: @KristofferCatabui, So, you are taking partial derivatives (with respect to $x, y,$ and $z$) of the integral $\int \dot x dt$?  I assume $\dot x$ means the time-derivative of $x$?

Comment: yes, that would be correct.